# Doctrine Migrations doesn't find generated version

Tags: zend-framework3, php-7.3, doctrine-migrations

I am trying to fill a database with tables, but I cant migrate to it after generating it.

I am using Zend Framework 3 and added doctrine-orm-module and migrations with the composer.phar file.
Strangely enough generating a new version works without problems. I'm executing the command like this:

```
./vendor/bin/doctrine-module migrations:generate
```

The new, empty version file appears in the folder I supplied, no problem. But when I want to migrate to it with

```
./vendor/bin/doctrine-module migrations:migrate
```

I get the error:

```
In NoMigrationsToExecute.php line 13:

  Could not find any migrations to execute.
```

Similar if I try execute:

```
./vendor/bin/doctrine-module migrations:execute 20191003105717
```

Error:

```
In UnknownMigrationVersion.php line 14:

  Could not find migration version 20191003105717
```

I'm using php7.3, MariaDb, and the code is in a vagrant box.

config\autoload\global.php

```
<?php

use Doctrine\DBAL\Driver\PDOMySql\Driver as PDOMySqlDriver;

return [
    'doctrine' => [
        'connection' => [
            'orm_default' => [
                'driverClass' => PDOMySqlDriver::class,
                'params' => [
                    'host'     => 'localhost',
                    'user'     => 'user',
                    'password' => 'pw',
                    'dbname'   => 'myDB',
                ]
            ],
        ],
        'migrations_configuration' => [
            'orm_default' => [
                'directory' => 'data/Migrations',
                'name'      => 'Doctrine Database Migrations',
                'namespace' => 'Migrations',
                'table'     => 'migrations',
            ],
        ],
    ],
];
```

I configured this according to these two tutorial chapters:
[Database Management with Doctrine ORM](https://olegkrivtsov.github.io/using-zend-framework-3-book/html/en/Database_Management_with_Doctrine_ORM.html)
[Database Migrations](https://olegkrivtsov.github.io/using-zend-framework-3-book/html/en/Database_Migrations.html)

Thanks for any help!

Edit:
Here is the output with full verbosity on:

```
./vendor/bin/doctrine-module migrations:migrate -vvv

                    Doctrine Database Migrations                    


WARNING! You are about to execute a database migration that could result in schema changes and data loss. Are you sure you wish to continue? (y/n)y
Migrating up to 0 from 0

In NoMigrationsToExecute.php line 13:

  [Doctrine\Migrations\Exception\NoMigrationsToExecute (4)]  
  Could not find any migrations to execute.                  


Exception trace:
  at /vagrant_data/vendor/doctrine/migrations/lib/Doctrine/Migrations/Exception/NoMigrationsToExecute.php:13
 Doctrine\Migrations\Exception\NoMigrationsToExecute::new() at /vagrant_data/vendor/doctrine/migrations/lib/Doctrine/Migrations/Migrator.php:137
 Doctrine\Migrations\Migrator->migrate() at /vagrant_data/vendor/doctrine/migrations/lib/Doctrine/Migrations/Tools/Console/Command/MigrateCommand.php:162
 Doctrine\Migrations\Tools\Console\Command\MigrateCommand->execute() at /vagrant_data/vendor/symfony/console/Command/Command.php:255
 Symfony\Component\Console\Command\Command->run() at /vagrant_data/vendor/symfony/console/Application.php:915
 Symfony\Component\Console\Application->doRunCommand() at /vagrant_data/vendor/symfony/console/Application.php:272
 Symfony\Component\Console\Application->doRun() at /vagrant_data/vendor/symfony/console/Application.php:148
 Symfony\Component\Console\Application->run() at /vagrant_data/vendor/doctrine/doctrine-module/bin/doctrine-module.php:45
 include() at /vagrant_data/vendor/doctrine/doctrine-module/bin/doctrine-module:4

migrations:migrate [--write-sql [WRITE-SQL]] [--dry-run] [--query-time] [--allow-no-migration] [--all-or-nothing [ALL-OR-NOTHING]] [--configuration [CONFIGURATION]] [--db-configuration [DB-CONFIGURATION]] [--object-manager [OBJECT-MANAGER]] [--] [<version>]
```

It does not seem to be a Migrations problem, but where could the error be then?

Comment: Have you deleted a migration file you have previously executed?

Comment: Also, try `migrate:diff`, it will generate the up & down functions necessary for a complete script based on the changes in your Entities.

Comment: Hello! I moved a migrations file out of the folder after it wouldn't work. As for 
`migrate:diff`, that's a whole other problem. There it says `In NoMappingFound.php line 13: No mapping information to process`. But I'd like for the simple migrations to work first before looking into that. Or do you think it's connected?

Comment: Your initial problem stems from you moving Migrations out of the `migrations/` folder. Migrations are registered as executed in the database (check, you'll find table `migrations` with timestamps). Move them back in or remove db records, I would suggest first. The second issue (`NoMappingFound`) could be that you've moved the `entity/` folder or have removed the `@ORM\Entity` Annotation from your Entity classes?

Comment: The tables migrations is empty and even if I create a new migration it stays empty. But there is a connection to the database because otherwise it would complain about that.
The Entity folder is where it usually is in the Zend Framework 3 folder structure. `/module/Application/src/Entity`

Comment: My gut feeling says it is a problem with the directories. Can you change the property of 'directory' to a full path (for example: /var/www/my/data/migrations) and try again? Please make sure the migration class file is in the correct directory.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, but that also didn't work. It's strange as there are no errors and one part of it is working (generate). I have basically given up on this problem for now and I'm working with the original database.

Comment: It works now. I updated Virtual Box and the vagrant box and after some rebuilding of the box it magically worked. So it was definitely a vagrant/virtual box problem. Thanks for the help. How do I close this now?

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem and I solved modifying the `migration_namespace` with the right one which you can find in the generated version class.